# Ordenar por mês sem repetir o ano

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Gostaria de somar o total de venda no mês, mas sem repetir o ano.

```
select EXTRACT(year FROM v.dataVenda),
case when EXTRACT(MONTH FROM v.dataVenda) =1 then sum(v.valorvenda) else 0 end as Jan,
case when EXTRACT(MONTH FROM v.dataVenda)= 2 then sum(v.valorvenda) else 0 end as Fev,
case when EXTRACT(MONTH FROM v.dataVenda)= 3 then sum(v.valorvenda) else 0 end as Mar,
case when EXTRACT(MONTH FROM v.dataVenda)= 4 then sum(v.valorvenda) else 0 end as Abr,
case when EXTRACT(MONTH FROM v.dataVenda)= 5 then sum(v.valorvenda) else 0 end as Mai,
case when EXTRACT(MONTH FROM v.dataVenda)= 6 then sum(v.valorvenda) else 0 end as Jun,
case when EXTRACT(MONTH FROM v.dataVenda)= 7 then sum(v.valorvenda) else 0 end as Jul,
case when EXTRACT(MONTH FROM v.dataVenda)= 8 then sum(v.valorvenda) else 0 end as Ago,
case when EXTRACT(MONTH FROM v.dataVenda)= 9 then sum(v.valorvenda) else 0 end as Set,
case when EXTRACT(MONTH FROM v.dataVenda)= 10 then sum(v.valorvenda) else 0 end as Out,
case when EXTRACT(MONTH FROM v.dataVenda)= 11 then sum(v.valorvenda) else 0 end as Nov,
case when EXTRACT(MONTH FROM v.dataVenda)= 12 then sum(v.valorvenda) else 0 end as Dez

from venda v

group by EXTRACT(year FROM v.dataVenda), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM v.dataVenda)
```

Saida:

```
ano   jan feb mar abr mai jun jul ago set out nov dez

2017; 0;  0; 0;  0;  0;  10;  0; 0;   0;  0;  0;  0                                    
2018; 0;  0; 0;  0;  0;  0;   0; 224; 0;  0;  0;  0

2018; 0;  0; 0;  0;  0;  0;   0; 0;   4;  0;  0;  0

2018; 0;  0; 0;  0;  0;  8;   0; 0;   10; 0;  0;  0
```

Gostaria que a saida fosse o ano e o total de cada mês:

```
ano jan feb mar abr mai jun jul ago set out nov dez                                            

2017; 0; 0 ;0; 0; 0; 10; 0 ;0 ;0; 0; 0; 0   
2018; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0 ;8 ;0; 224; 14; 0; 0; 0
```

Comment: Altere seu `group by` para `group by EXTRACT(year FROM v.dataVenda)`

Comment: Já tentei, portanto apresenta erro:
`ERROR:  column "v.datavenda" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 2:   case when EXTRACT(MONTH FROM v.dataVenda) =1 then sum(v.va...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que acontece é que novas linhas serão criadas para cada termo no `GROUP BY` que foi adicionado, portanto com o `EXTRACT MONTH` que está na sua `query`, um `SET` de resultados será criado para cada mês que for encontrado nos resultados. Então você deve tirar esse termo de lá. Quando fizer isso o banco irá pedir o agrupamento novamente porque seu `SUM` está sendo feito no lugar errado. Você deve somar fora do `CASE`. O resultado será similar ao seguinte:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM v.dataVenda),
       SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM v.dataVenda) = 1 then v.valorvenda else 0 end) as Jan,
       -- ... outros meses
       SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM v.dataVenda) = 12 then v.valorvenda else 0 end) as Dez,
  FROM venda v
 GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM v.dataVenda)
```

Comment: Obrigado @Sorack. 
Exatamente isso. Tinha tentado o Sum(Case...  e apresentava erro pois eu estava colocando o SUM também no ...THEN SUM(v.valorVenda) - Erro.
Mas agora deu certo! vlw